# Does MVVM violate DRY?

Tags: wpf, design-patterns, mvvm

It seems that ViewModels that I make look *suspiciously like other classes* and they seem to require a lot of code repetition, e.g. in a current project I have:

- **SmartForm**: *Model* that represents a data form to fill in, has properties:

  - IdCode
  - Title
  - Description
  - collection of SmartFormFields
  - etc.
- **SmartFormControlView** *View*
- **SmartFormControlViewModel** *ViewModel*

  - IdCode
  - Title
  - Description
  - collection of SmartFormFields
  - etc.

So my **ViewModel is basically the same as my Model**, just with all the OnPropertyChanged features for binding with the View.

It seems as I refactor and extend this that every little change I make to my model, I **have to make a** **mirror change to the ViewModel**.

This seems to violate a basic rule of patterns *Don't Repeat Yourself*.

**Am I implementing the MVVM pattern incorrectly or is it just an inherent characteristic of MVVM that there is always a 1-to-1 repetition going on between Model and ViewModel?**

Comment: I've often wondered the same thing... except in my case, I _do_ choose to implement change notifications on my Models as well (makes more sense to me -- they're where the data is stored, so they're the ones who would know when it changed). That makes the repetition stand out even more.

Comment: My approach is that models should be able to be used in any environment, so if you want to use them in an ASP.NET MVC application, you don't want change notifications on them. So I would think the change notifications on your models make them locked into a WPF environment, right?

Comment: Why not just have an instance of SmartForm class in the SmartFormControlViewModel, instead of replicating the fields?

Comment: No, change notifications wouldn't lock you into WPF. They'd just be unnecessary in other environments. (INotifyPropertyChanged is in System.dll, so it's part of the core .NET Framework, not part of any WPF-specific library.) But I do like your reasoning -- that's something I hadn't thought of.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I personally don't think it violates DRY since the model and view-model (I prefer the term presenter) don't point to the same information.  For instance your VM and M both have a Title property, but your VM's Title property could also include validation, whereas your model's Title property could assume validity.

While it's true that The VM may contain all of the properties of the model, there is also the possibility of having validations (e.g. Title must be non-blank), data-dependencies, bindable UI-specific properties (icons, colors, brushes, etc.) which aren't part of the view.

Essentially all UI patterns have similar "duplication" in the way you state it: namely cascading modifications.  Try changing a model in MVC without changing the controller.

That being said, MVVM (or any UI pattern designed to separate UI, logic, and state) can be overly tedious for simple cases such as your example.  When logic becomes little more than state-pass through, the value separating the controller/presenter/view-model decreases.

In your specific case, if there really isn't any logic, validation, or UI specific properties that your VM isn't surfacing, and your model doesn't have to be persisted, serialized, or made backwards compatible with an existing structure (or adding the logic to do so in your VM is trivial), I would strongly consider combining the M and VM to avoid creating properties whose sole purpose is to get/set the underlying model's properties.

Comment: I would never, ever assume validity at the model level.  A major benefit of abstracting out the model is that you can replace the UI layer with something else (a different UI, a web service) and gain code reuse.  If you delegate model validation to the original UI, the model becomes impossible to correctly re-use.

Comment: @ Eric J: Late reply, but you make an excellent point.  In most of the MVVM examples and suggested by the WPF/SL binding infrastructure itself, the models are behaviorally light (e.g. Fowler's anemic domain model) deferring validation to databind-time, e.g. the VM layer.  I'm curious as to your thoughts and approaches regarding databinding and limiting its intrusion into domain models while at the same time relying on the domain models for validation.

Comment: @EricJ., on contrary, the domain model (aggregate) invariants must be enforced to provide model **consistency**. What is the purpose of a model if it does not to enforce its own consistency?

Comment: @SergeyBrunov: Isn't that what I said?

Comment: @EricJ., please excuse me. I didn't catch the last sentence of your previous message. This is exactly the same.

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution is to have an abstract ViewModel(VM) base class that exposes the model. You can choose this VM in scenarios where it makes sense.

i.e.

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase<T>
{
    public T Model { get; set; }
}
```

If you Model has INotifyPropertyChanged implemented your view will get the event. What this does do is give your View access to every property in your Model which isn't what you want some times.

also you can utilize property initializers like this(which I personally have stored in code snippets):

```
public abstract class SampleViewModel
{
    public int MyProperty
    {
        get { return Model.MyProperty; }
        set
        {
            Model.MyProperty = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MyProperty");
        }
    }
}
```

In most circumstances you view will be the one making changes to your VM and when it does any control that is bound to that property will then be told that something happened.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

That's an interesting remark... indeed, it's often necessary to modify the ViewModel to reflect the changes in the Model.

It would be nice if it could be automatic... actually I think it could be possible, by implementing ICustomTypeDescriptor in the ViewModel : GetProperties would return all the properties of the model through reflection. However I'm not sure it would make sense, because the model may not consist of properties at all : it could be methods, fields, or anything, and not everything in the model would be useful in the ViewModel.

Comment: currently I'm handling it through snippets and code generation, I would suspect/hope that there will be more support for MVVM coming with new version of WPF and Visual Studio so that ViewModels can be created perhaps with Entity Frameworks, etc. perhaps this is already possible in EF 4.0?

Comment: "perhaps this is already possible in EF 4.0?" : well, I didn't see anything specific about MVVM in .NET 4.0... Perhaps Microsoft will provide something in the form of a toolkit, like they did initially for ASP.NET AJAX, and the WPF toolkit (which has been partially included in WPF 4)

Answer (score 1):

Others have provided good comments on the roles of the components of the MVC/MVVM patterns.  I would like to offer a fundamental observation explaining the repetitiveness no matter which pattern you select.

Generally there will be some sort of repetition between your data layer, business layer and UI layer.  After all, in general you have to *show* each property to the end user (UI), *model* it's behavior (Business layer) and *persist* the value (data layer).

As others have pointed out, the property might be treated a bit differently on each layer which explains the fundamental need for some duplication.

When working on systems large enough (or on small projects with the right team), I tend to model this type of information in UML, and use code generation (often coupled with partial classes) to handle the repetitive aspects.  As a simple example, the Last Name property might have a requirement (in my UML model) that it limit data to 50 characters.  I can generate code to enforce that limit into my UI layer (e.g. by physically limiting input), generate code into my business layer to recheck that limitation ("never trust the UI") by perhaps throwing an Exception if the data is too long, and generate my persistence layer (e.g. NVARCHAR(50) column, appropriate ORM mapping file, etc.).

**2012 Update**

Microsoft's [Data Annotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.aspx) and their support in the UI layer (e.g. [ASP.Net MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/models-%28data%29/validation-with-the-data-annotation-validators-cs)) and on the data layer ([Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg193958)) goes a long way toward implementing many of the concerns I previously generated code for.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that seems to have been missed here and that your simplistic example does not expose is the fact that your Views will often aggregate data that is contained within multiple Domain Model types. In this case your ViewModels will contain references to a number of domain Models (of differing types) thus aggregating a bunch of related data that a particular View may wish to expose.

Answer (score 1):

Eric Evans, in his book "Domain Driven Design" mentions that Model refactoring should not be too hard, and that a concept change should not span into too many modules, otherwise, refactoring the Model becomes prohibitive, so, if you ask me, having the Model sort of 'copied' in the ViewModel certainly difficults Model refactoring.

Eric mentions that one should give more weight to Model cohesion and isolation, than to a tidiness in the division of layers based on technical concerns (database access, POCOS, presentation). That the most important concern is that the Domain Model is a good representation of the Business Domain, hence its the most important for the Domain Model to be in a single isolated layer, and not spanned in several modules, in order for it to be easily updated (refactored).

Considering what was just said, I'd use the same Model object in the ViewModel, and if I want to reduce the level of "access" to a Model object, then I'd "pass" a reference to an Interface implemented by the Model object. For example:

```
    // The primary Model classes
    public partial class OrderItem {
        public int Id { get; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public Product Item { get; set; }
        public int Total { get; set; }
        public void ApplyDiscount(Coupon coupon) {
            // implementation here
        }
    }

    public partial class Product {
        public int Id { get; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }    
    }

    // The shared views of those model classes
    public partial class OrderItem : IOrderItemDTO {
        public IProductDTO Item { 
            get { 
                return this.product; 
            } 
        }
    }

    public partial class Product : IProductDTO {
    }


   // Separate interfaces...
   // You enforce the rules about how the model can be
   // used in the View-ViewModel, without having to rewrite
   // all the setters and getters.
    public interface IOrderItemDTO {
        int Id { get; }
        int Quantity { get; set; }
        IProductDTO Item { get; }
        int Total { get; }
    }

    public interface IProductDTO {
        string Name { get; }
        string Description { get; }
        decimal Price { get; }
    }

    // The viewmodel...
    public class OrderItemViewModel {
        IOrderItemDTO Model { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I only know MVC and in MVC a Model-Class which contains GUI is some error. SmartForm seems to be a Form, which means it is not a model. I don't know what you are trying to program but I give you an example for a Model:

Take a Calender. You can ask the Class what date it is today, what month, how many days each month has, ...
It has no graphical representation though. The View (CalenderViewMonth or whater you want) prints a single Month on screen. It knows a Calender and asks him what to write in the different cells.

Essentially - you might have something wrong in your modeling / understanding of MVVM (which is a modern .NET-Variant of MVC).

---

Edit:

I just looked up MVVM on Wikipedia. Model is just like the Model in MVC. View like the View in MVC as well - only graphical representation. the ViewModel is the Glue between a generic View and a specialized Model. Some kind of Adapter. There should be no violation of DRY.

Comment: SmartForm is just a data holder that determines how a UI Form will look, in MVVM, the View would just connect to the Model if it could, but the Model doesn't have any "binding magic" (OnPropertyChanged, ObservableCollection) and so you have to create a ViewModel which is basically the same as the Model but has these binding features, a ViewModel might not have to implement ALL of the properties and functionality of the model for a specific view, but in my experience it often does and so VM = M + binding magic.

Comment: I agree, the duplication here comes from a useless layer (SmartForm).

Answer (score 0):

I think that yes, vanilla MVVM does violate DRY. But I've started [the PDX library](http://code.google.com/p/pdx/) which I think can solve this problem in many cases. I wrote [this post](http://defaultkramer.blogspot.com/2011/05/databinding-to-pocos-with-pdx.html) which I believe addresses this question.

Basically, my goal (one of them) is to have Viewmodels that don't worry about UI Notification. The PDX project is still in its infancy but if you're reading this question you might find it useful, and I would appreciate any feedback you may have.